# Convergence of averaged sine function

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have stumbled upon those two problems which I got a little stuck on that is show convergence or divergence for the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(n)}{n}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(n)}{n}.$$

Comment: Hint: trig functions oscillate $[-1,1] $. That might help you use the direct comparision test.

Comment: Note that, if these series converge, then so does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\left(\cos(n)+i \sin (n)\right)$. Writing $z=e^{i \phi}$, this means that we're really asking about the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}=-\log(1-z)$ on the boundary of the complex unit circle.

Comment: @Semiclassical: can't you just use the direct comparison, with like $\sum^\infty_1 {\frac {1}{2n}} $ which is smaller, or decays faster?

Comment: 1) Had a dumb typo in my first comment: should have $z=e^i=\cos 1 +i \sin 1$ (which is in the first quadrant). 2) @dylan7: I don't see how direct comparison helps here: the terms of that divergent series don't bound either trig function from below.

Comment: Maybe I didn't quite understood the answers but wouldn't the direct comparison test suggested this way would just give an upper bound of +∞?

Comment: @Semiclassical: True. I feel like I have seen something similar where the direct comparison has been used where the series has a trig function in it. Maybe I am confusing something else.

Comment: @user2900110: Forget the direct comparison. Yeah it only bounds it from above. It doesn't work. My bad. I was confusing this series with another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer is not entirely rigorous as written, but you can actually sum these series explicitly. Moreover I will proceed a bit more generically by considering $\{\cos n\phi,\sin n\phi\}$ for some real $\phi\in(0,\pi]$. (The case $\phi=0$ would give the divergent harmonic series, and other real $\phi$ can be determined by symmetry & periodicity.) Recalling Euler's formula $e^{i \phi}=\cos\phi+i \sin \phi$, observe that

$$f(\phi):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos n\phi}{n}+i \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin n\phi}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i n\phi}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$$

where $z:=e^{i \phi}$. We may recognize this last expression in terms of the Taylor series of the logarithm as $f(\phi)=-\ln(1-z)=-\ln(1-e^{i\phi}).$ (To check this, compute $f'(z)$ term by term and sum the resulting geometric series.) This can be simplified by observing that 
$$1-e^{i \phi}=e^{i\phi/2}\left(e^{-i\phi/2}-e^{i\phi/2}\right)=-2i e^{i\phi/2}\sin\frac{\phi}{2} = \left(2\sin\frac{\phi}{2}\right) e^{i(\phi-\pi)/2}.$$ and so $f(\phi)=-\ln\left(2\sin\dfrac{\phi}{2}\right)-i\left(\dfrac{\phi-\pi}{2}\right)$. As a check, note that $f(\pi)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n}(-1)^n=-\ln 2$. With this in hand, we have $f(1)=-\ln\left(2\sin\dfrac{1}{2}\right)+i\left(\dfrac{\pi-1}{2}\right)$; to get the cosine and sine series, simply take the real and imaginary parts respectively. So we have summed the series.

Answer (score 2):

Use Dirichlet's test. The sequence $a_n = \dfrac 1n$ decreases to zero, and the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos n$ has bounded partial sums (this takes a little trigonometry to justify). This implies $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n}{n}$ converges.

The other series is treated similarly.

Comment: Can you give a reference or a short reasoning as to why the cosine or sine series converges?

Comment: The series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos n$ is definitely divergent (but even that is immaterial). What is important is that its partial sums are bounded.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Fourier analysis to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n)/n$ as follows.

The key is the [Poisson summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula): if $f(x)$ has Fourier transform $\hat{f}(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi i u t} dt$, then
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(k)$$
If we define
$$f(x) = \begin{align}
1 & \text{ if }|x| < \frac{1}{2\pi} \\
0 & \text{ otherwise} \\
\end{align}$$
then
$$\begin{align}
\hat{f}(u) &= \int_{-1/(2\pi)}^{1/(2\pi)} e^{-2\pi i u t} dt \\
&= \frac{e^{i u} - e^{- i u}}{2\pi i u}\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}
\end{align}$$

Observe that
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = 1$$
since only the $n=0$ index lies within the interval $[-1/(2\pi), 1/(2\pi)]$.
Therefore the Poisson summation formula gives us
$$1 = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(k) = 
\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(k)}{k}$$
Rearranging, we conclude that
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(k)}{k} = \pi$$
Since $\sin(k)/k$ is even, we have
$$\pi = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(k)}{k} = 1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(k)}{k}$$
so
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(k)}{k} = \frac{\pi - 1}{2}$$

Comment: I actually really liked this derivation I don't know how it never occurred to me to use the sinc function as part of the poison summation formula  but I chose the another since the other one is more intuitive and gives solution to both series

Comment: @user2900110: Understood. I like Semiclassical's solution even better than this one. :-) But it's nice to attack problems using various techniques. By the way, my solution isn't completely rigorous either, as the usual statements of the Poisson summation formula require $f$ to be continuous (and even a bit nicer than that). But I'm pretty sure one can make it rigorous by approximating $f$ with a $C^\infty$ function and then using a limiting argument. Offhand I'm not sure how you could apply this technique to sum $\cos(n)/n$, though.

Answer (score -4):

We know that $(-1) \le \cos n$

So $(-1)/n \le \cos n/n$

Summation $(-1)/n$ is divergent. So by Comparison test of first type, summation $\cos n/n$ is divergent.

Comment: If I follow you, $-1\leq0$, so $-1/n\leq0/n$, and since the sum of $-1/n$ is divergent, then so is the sum of $0/n$. Quite bogus...

Comment: The comparison test says that if $u_n\leq kv_n$ for all $n$, then divergence of $sum {u_n}$ implies divergence of $sum {v_n}$. $(-1)\leq cosn$ for all $n>m, m\in N$, so why can't I apply the comparison test here then? The real reason I am wrong here is because this test only works for a series of positive real numbers, and $sum cosn$ isn't one. :) Neither is $sum \frac{(-1)}{n}$ for that matter, which is why the test fails in your counter example. :) I was wrong, yes, and I learnt, so thank you for criticizing but not pointing out WHERE I was wrong so I could figure it out myself. :)

Comment: No need to blame me. I showed you it couln't work, seeing that it was because of sign should have been a logical consequence: by the way your test would work with series of negative numbers, just reverse the inequalities (actually that's what I wanted you to see, that your inequality was not in the correct direction, since it would forbid convergence of series with small terms). Of course it does not work with series of mixed sign. In my opinion, finding by yourself is a better way to learn from your mistake. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No, no, it wasn't inconvenient, I'm glad I learnt. I haven't learnt convergence of negative series, so I missed what you wanted to show, sorry. :)

Comment: For negative series, just reverse the sign to get a positive series, and apply the usual test. Since you change sign, inequalities are reversed. That's all you have to know about it. However, it does not workd with mixed sign, of course.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind next time. :)